# GitHub for Windows Pre-Commit Hook

Tags: git, github

We have a development team that is using a 50/50 split of GitHub for windows and Bash shell for their Git management.

We have implemented a pre-commit hook (designed to run unit tests and fail the commit when tests fail). As a simplified version I have attached a cut down version below which demos our issue.

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 1
```

If we attempt a commit from the bash shell, the commit as expected fails. However if we perform the same commit from the GitHub for windows application it is successfully committed to the local repo.

So Does anyone know how we can get the same functionality from GitHub application? Unfortunately we can't move the users off the application, and its now an obvious hole.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: While I like the idea of GitHub for Windows, I have personally found it slow and even bugged in some cases. I wouldn't recommend it for production teams as of yet.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the github for windows team for support ? You can mail them at support@github.com

Comment: @nightcracker - the newer version seems more stable, but as its easy to just download and install it, we need to plug this hole.

Comment: @ksol - thank you, we did give them a go, but heard nothing back yet, so opened it to the community.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but GitHub for Windows doesn't support pre-commit hooks, since it uses libgit2 to commit.

Comment: You are quite correct, we got this response from github:

Unfortunately GitHub for Windows doesn't support pre-commit hooks, since we don't actually use git.exe to commit (we use a project called libgit2, which is much faster than git.exe but doesn't support certain features). If you rely on these, you might have to use the Git Shell to make commits instead.

Comment: Pretty sure I wrote that response :)

Comment: Is it only pre-commit hooks that Github for Windows can't execute?

Comment: While certain other hooks may currently execute, they probably won't in the future

Answer (score 2):

Using Git shell you can have commit hooks.  I got some commit hooks working with PowerShell.  I found a [powerShell](https://gist.github.com/1034262) script that did lint that I expanded to run phpunit and phpcs (paths are hard coded so you will need to adjust):

pre Commit File:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo 
exec powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -File '.\.git\hooks\pre-commit-hook.ps1'
exit
```

pre-commit.ps1 file:

```
###############################################################################
#
# PHP Syntax Check for Git pre-commit hook for Windows PowerShell
#
# Author: Vojtech Kusy <wojtha@gmail.com>
# Author: Chuck "MANCHUCK" Reeves <chuck@manchuck.com>
#
###############################################################################

### INSTRUCTIONS ###

# Place the code to file "pre-commit" (no extension) and add it to the one of 
# the following locations:
# 1) Repository hooks folder - C:\Path\To\Repository\.git\hooks
# 2) User profile template   - C:\Users\<USER>\.git\templates\hooks 
# 3) Global shared templates - C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\share\git-core\templates\hooks
# 
# The hooks from user profile or from shared templates are copied from there
# each time you create or clone new repository.

### SETTINGS ###

# Path to the php.exe
$php_exe = "C:\php\php.exe";

# Path to the phpcs
$php_cs = "C:\Includes\PEAR\phpcs.bat";

# Path to the phpunit
$php_unit = "C:\Includes\PEAR\phpunit.bat";

# Path to the phpunit bootstrap file
$bootstrap = "tests\bootstrap.php";

# Flag, if set to 1 require test file to exist, set to 0 to disable
$requireTest = 1;

# Extensions of the PHP files 
$php_ext = "php|phtml"

# Flag, if set to 1 git will unstage all files with errors, set to 0 to disable
$unstage_on_error = 0;

### FUNCTIONS ###

function php_syntax_check {
    param([string]$php_bin, [string]$extensions, [int]$reset) 

    $err_counter = 0;

    write-host "Pre-commit PHP syntax check:" -foregroundcolor "white" -backgroundcolor "black"

    git diff-index --name-only --cached HEAD -- | foreach {             
        if ($_ -match ".*\.($extensions)$") {
            $file = $matches[0];
            $errors = & $php_bin -l $file   
            $testFileExists = (Test-Path $file -PathType Leaf)
            write-host $file ": "  -foregroundcolor "gray"  -backgroundcolor "black" -NoNewline
            if ($testFileExists) {
                if ($errors -match "No syntax errors detected in $file") {
                    write-host "OK!" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
                }
                else {              
                    write-host "ERROR! " $errors -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    if ($reset) {
                        git reset -q HEAD $file
                        write-host "Unstaging ..." -foregroundcolor "magenta" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    }
                    $err_counter++
                }
            } else {
                write-host "OK! (file deleted)" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
            }
        }
    }

    if ($err_counter -gt 0) {
        write-host "Some File(s) have syntax errors. Please fix then commit" -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
        exit 1
    }    
}

function php_cs_check {
    param([string]$php_cs, [string]$extensions, [int]$reset) 

    $err_counter = 0;

    write-host "Pre-commit PHP codesniffer check:" -foregroundcolor "white" -backgroundcolor "black"

    git diff-index --name-only --cached HEAD -- | foreach {     
        if ($_ -match ".*\.($extensions)$") {
            $file = $matches[0];

            write-host $file ": "  -foregroundcolor "gray"  -backgroundcolor "black" -NoNewline
            if ($file -match "tests\/") {
                write-host "PASSED! (test file)" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
            } else {
                $errors = & $php_cs --standard=Zend $file           

                if ($LastExitCode) {
                    write-host "FAILED! (contains errors)"  -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    if ($reset) {
                        git reset -q HEAD $file
                        write-host "Unstaging ..." -foregroundcolor "magenta" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    }
                    $err_counter++
                } else {                
                    write-host "PASSED!" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if ($err_counter -gt 0) {
        write-host "Some File(s) are not following proper codeing standards. Please fix then commit" -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
        exit 1
    }    
}

function php_unit_check {
    param([string]$php_unit, [string]$bootstrap, [string]$extensions, [int]$reset, [int]$requireTest) 

    $err_counter = 0;

    write-host "Pre-commit PHP unit check:" -foregroundcolor "white" -backgroundcolor "black"

    git diff-index --name-only --cached HEAD -- | foreach {     
        if ($_ -match ".*\.($extensions)$") {
            $file = $matches[0];

            write-host $file ": "  -foregroundcolor "gray"  -backgroundcolor "black" -NoNewline
            if ($file -match "tests\/") {
                write-host "SKIPPED! (test file)" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
            } elseif ($file -match ".*Bootstrap.php") {
                write-host "SKIPPED! (bootstrap file)" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"
            } elseif ($file -match "([application|library\\NDX].*)(.($extensions))$") {

                $testFile = 'tests/' + $matches[1] + "Test.php";
                $testFileExists = (Test-Path $testFile -PathType Leaf)

                if ($testFileExists) {
                    $errors = & $php_unit --bootstrap $bootstrap $testFile
                    if ($LastExitCode) {
                        write-host "FAILED! (" $testFile ")"  -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
                        if ($reset) {
                            git reset -q HEAD $file
                            write-host "Unstaging ..." -foregroundcolor "magenta" -backgroundcolor "black"
                        }
                        $err_counter++
                    } else {
                        write-host "PASSED!" -foregroundcolor "green" -backgroundcolor "black"

                    }
                } elseif($requireTest) {
                    write-host "FAILED! Test file Not found: (" $testFile ")"  -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    if ($reset) {
                        git reset -q HEAD $file
                        write-host "Unstaging ..." -foregroundcolor "magenta" -backgroundcolor "black"
                    }
                    $err_counter++
                } else {
                    write-host "PASSED! (Test file not found and not required)" -foregroundcolor "darkGreen" -backgroundcolor "black"
                }
            } else {
                write-host "IGNORED!" -foregroundcolor "darkGreen" -backgroundcolor "black"
            }
        }
    }

    if ($err_counter -gt 0) {
        write-host "Some File(s) failed unit testing. Please fix then commit" -foregroundcolor "red" -backgroundcolor "black"
        exit 1
    }    
}
### MAIN ###

php_syntax_check $php_exe "php|phtml" $unstage_on_error
write-host
php_cs_check $php_cs "php" $unstage_on_error
write-host
php_unit_check $php_unit $bootstrap "php" $unstage_on_error $requireTest
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding an answer as the currently selected answer is no longer the case.  I was able to write a pre-commit hook that works across GitHub Desktop for Windows, SourceTree for Windows, and Git Bash for Windows.

I'm not sure if it's a hard requirement for windows commit hooks, but I included an exact reference to sh.exe like so:

```
#!C:/Program\ Files/Git/usr/bin/sh.exe
```

And it runs fine!

Answer (score 0):

You may look into using Visual Studio (or your builder) pre-build events, although there is a gotcha there too if full automation needed. [Here is an example use.](http://blog.didenko.com/2013/11/version-inventory.html) Now, that solution also requires `git.exe` on the path, but user does not need to interact with it. And it would be sweet if someone smarter than me can solve that backslash issue mentioned in the write-up.