# Hook git command into visual studio pre build step

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, git

I'm using git as version control and I'm trying to hook the SHA1 of the current commit into a visual studio build as a define.

So basically I want to turn the output of the command

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

into a define that I can embed in the output binary.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Frankly, I prefer a pre-build events in Visual Studio over Git post-commit. There is additional benefit of knowing if you building from a dirty repository or not. Did the write-up on that today. Here are the general steps from build to execution:

The build process has a pre-build script, which gathers version and repository status information. In our case, VC++ uses the Windows PowerShell `version_info.ps1` script.

The pre-build script generates a source code file, which is expected by the rest of the codebase. The generated file has everything needed to allow or deny running the version. In our case it is a C++ header file `version.h`.

A code contains function which checks if the build is legitimate to run, and logs and stops the process as needed. That example code is in the `versionLogAndVet` function of the `version.cpp` example file.

At run time, the `versionLogAndVet` function allows to run only permitted combinations of repository status / build configuration. It also logs version information.

[The specifics and code examples are at the full post](http://blog.didenko.com/2013/11/version-inventory.html).

Answer (score 1):

Using a `post-commit` [githook](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html), you can put it into a file. I *think* git on windows comes with a bourne shell, so the following would work in a post-commit hook.

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_SHA_INCLUDE_FILE=foo.h
echo -n '#define GIT_SHA ' > $GIT_SHA_INCLUDE_FILE
git rev-parse HEAD >> $GIT_SHA_INCLUDE_FILE
```

And save that as .git/hooks/post-commit

The file should remain untracked since it's (nearly) impossible to include the hash of the commit within the commit itself.

Comment: Here's one gotcha that might be an issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410164/github-for-windows-pre-commit-hook