# Is it possible to add a "Precommit hook" on TFS?

Tags: git, tfs, gruntjs, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit

We want every person that does a push in our git repository to run "grunt" before this is done. We enforce this by having a pre-push hook in `.git/hooks/pre-push` and writing `npm install` and `grunt` in that file.

We also have a TFS repository. I am looking for similar logic to be used here. Meaning, we want a sort of "Gated check-in" when someone tries to check something in. This will only starts up PowerShell and runs `npm install` and `grunt` *locally*.

We don't want TFS to do anything else (run build, run tests etc. (all this is done in the grunt task)).

Is this possible? Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

TFS has nothing to do with what you do locally. You can add as many pre-commit hooks to your repo and push them to TFS. TFS will happily store these hook scripts. ANd when you are using a client that supports them, that client will execute them pre-commit.

But if you expect Visual Studio to run these hooks before commit, you're probably out of luck. There is no "check-in policy" support for Visual Studio when connected to Git. Nor in any other Git client based on LibGit2 at present as far as I can tell.

You could setup a branch policy linked to a CI build, effectively running the grunt tasks on a build server, but I understand this is not what you want. .

There's some background available on the LibGit2 issue section, [which is what Visual Studio uses to implement its git functionality](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/issues/964). And this corresponding [user voice item for Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/4321705-enable-client-side-hooks-when-committing-code-to-a). As [well as a discussion on the GitHub for Windows client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12410164/github-for-windows-pre-commit-hook) which uses the same underlying library.